# React Native FBSDK LoginButton does not work on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using [FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) to integrate Facebook Login. The button work fine on iOS but does not do anything on Android. I am using the latest release `0.7.0` of FBSDK.

I can see the Login dialog appearing and can input credentials just fine. After the login flow is completed neither of the `then` or `catch` branches of the promise from `LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile'])` is called.

I tried debugging by logging to logcat by modifying the `onSuccess` method in `FBLoginManagerModule`, and the `onCancel` and `onError` methods in `ReactNativeFacebookSDKCallback` classes. None of them are in fact called, explaining the promise not being fulfilled.

I have followed all the steps integrating the SDK as per the official docs. Also, since everything works fine on iOS, I am not sure what exactly is wrong with Android. There are exactly zero errors in the process, just the login does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @gargsms that was the trick. To elaborate `setActivityCallbacks` must be added to the `public void onCreate` method and you must include `import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.ActivityCallbacks;` and `import android.content.Intent;`

```
import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.ActivityCallbacks;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setActivityCallbacks(new ActivityCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        });
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I had to explicitly add activity callbacks in my `MainApplication.java`

This worked fine:

```
setActivityCallbacks(new ActivityCallbacks() {
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit old, but I spent 2 hours making it works on Android.

For those coming from react-native-fbsdk-next and getting the same problem, you have to add the "LoginManager.logInWithPermissions" from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login).

So your code will looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

import {AccessToken, LoginButton, LoginManager} from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';

import {View} from 'react-native';

const Signin = () => {

  LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile']).then(
    function (result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log('Login cancelled');
      } else {
        console.log(
          'Login success with permissions: ' +
            result.grantedPermissions.toString(),
        );
      }
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
    },
  );

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <LoginButton
        onLoginFinished={(error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log('login has error: ' + result.error);
          } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            console.log('login is cancelled.');
          } else {
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
              console.log(data.accessToken.toString());
            });
          }
        }}
        onLogoutFinished={() => console.log('logout.')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Signin;
```